# Disable HREF within P element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, href

I'm using wordpress 4.8 and plugin WPDISCUZ for commenting system. How do I disable **ONLY this HREF** within this plugin from functioning (become regular span) while other href still work normally? I mean I don't want my reader to click this link accidentally or intentionally and sent to admin login page but instead they can login via their social network on comment fields. Is there any way to fix this using Javascript/jQuery?

Image:
[image: Screenshot]

CSS from view source.

```
<p class="wc-must-login">You must be <a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.example.com/admin-login-page/">logged in</a> to post a comment. </p>
```

**NOTE:**

1. This CSS is from plugin. I cannot add/remove class to it.
2. I don't want to change CSS class wc-must-login to display:none. Reason: Reader need to know they have to login to leave a comment.

**EDIT:**
I thought only Javascript / jQuery can achieve this while CSS only for styling. But thanks to Farhad Bagherlo seems it can be achieve with similar effect using CSS.

Comment: A 5 minute scan of the documentation would have revealed the possible answer. http://wpdiscuz.com/wpdiscuz-documentation/ scroll to Default Article setting and item Allow people to post comments on new articles

Comment: @jeff Sorry. I have no idea what do you mean. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wc-must-login a {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<p class="wc-must-login"><a target="_blank" href="https://us.yahoo.com/">link</a></p>
```

Comment: This also can't work unfortunately. Seems I'm stuck now

Comment: OMG.. It works perfectly just like I wanted. I thought only with Javascript/jQuery can achieve this and CSS only for styling. Thank you very very much Sir. You save me from headache! I'll edit my question and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wc-must-login a").attr("disabled", "true");
})
```

Comment: I tried this but can't get it to work. I also add $j=jQuery.noConflict(); change $ to $j but still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this jQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p.wc-must-login > a").attr("href", "#");
})
```

Comment: I tried your code too but can't get it to work. I also add $j=jQuery.noConflict(); like I did on above answer but still can't get it to work.